# Metabase does not show the same value between the "table view" and a "visualisation view"

Tags: metabase

I want to display some values with a simple horizontal bar chart with a native SQL request. the result is ok when it's showed as a table, but the chart is not right, with random wrong values.

Here is the score I want to display, first value is at 1.11, second is 0.49 and so on.
[Data when looking at the table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5fjS.png)

Here is the score when ploting with any type of chart, the first value is now over 1.5.
[Data when looking at the visualisation view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ71l.png)

Do any one know what's going on ?

I already tried to change the SQL request and to change the type of chart but nothing works.